# how to sort array of dictionary alphabetically in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am getting array of dictionary and I want to sort that data alphabetically to show indexed tableview functionality.how can i sort array with dictionary to implement indexed tableview.to sort array here is my code:

```
NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:resultArray];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"first_name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseSensitive)] ;
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];
sortedArray = [array1 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

I am trying with code but, when i am displaying data in tableview its getting mismatch.Please suggest me correct way. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try below posted answer and did you get any solution?

Comment: it is pretty much the same as it would be in iOS8, iOS7, 6, 5, ...etc...

Answer (score 0):

please use this code:

```
NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:resultArray];
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: YES];
array1 = [array1 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSArray *arr = @[@{@"first_name":@"B"},@{@"first_name":@"A"}];
 NSSortDescriptor *desc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"first_name" ascending:YES];
arr =  [arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[desc]];
```

Answer (score 0):

We Got The Solution By Using The Method Follows

```
[self.jsonData sortUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:"fullname" ascending:YES], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:"id" ascending:NO], nil]];
```

Where:-

jsonData - MutableArray Which holds the Parsed JSON Data.

fullname - the data we want to sort.

id - An unique data which comes with the inner dictionary.

Ref: [how to sort array of dictionary alphabetically in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418227/how-to-sort-array-of-dictionary-alphabetically-in-ios-9)

Answer (score 0):

try this

let sortedKeys = (self.dictBrands.allKeys as! [String]).sort(<)
       self.arrAllBrandsTitle =  NSMutableArray(array: sortedKeys)